# Como conseguir injetar dependências com Weblogic 12.x.x?

Tags: java, injeção-de-dependência, java-ee-7

Qual o procedimento para conseguir injetar dependências utilizando `@Inject` do `javax.inject` no servidor Weblogic 12.x.x? Preciso baixar o Weld e colocá-lo nas dependências do projeto?

Eu notei que o Weblogic sequer reconhece a anotação

Testei tanto com meu beans.xml vazio (funcionou no jboss 7.1.1) como com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
<beans></beans>
```

Dentro da classe que pretendo injetar meu Stateless Session Bean, simplesmente fiz a referência assim:

```
@Inject
private TransFacadeLocal transfacade;
```

E ao tentar utilizá-lo este esta sempre nulo, resultando numa NullPointerException ao tentar referenciá-lo.

A classe concreta do meu Stateless Session Bean é a seguinte:

```
//imports omitidos
@Stateless(mappedName = "transFacade")
@LocalBean
public class TransFacade implements TransFacadeLocal{


   public TransFacade{}
   //outros métodos omitidos

}
```

A interface local que estou utilizando para injetar é a seguinte:

```
//imports omitidos
@Local
public interface TransFacadeLocal{//... metodos omitidos}
```

Para reconhecer as libs como @Inject do javax.inject por exemplo eu fiz sem referenciar o weld propriamente dito, mas aproveitando libs que ja vieram na distribuição junto com o OEPE/weblogic. São elas:

- wljarbuilder.jar
  ...Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib
- weblogic.jar ...Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib
- weblogic.server.merged.jar ...Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules\features

  Error 500--Internal Server Error

  org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [TesteLocal] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private br.com.programa.teste.ServletTest.testeLocal]. Possible dependencies [[Managed Bean [class br.com.programa.Teste] with qualifiers [@Any @Default], Session bean [class br.com.programa.Teste with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [Teste, TesteLocal], Managed Bean [class br.com.programa.Teste] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]]]
      at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:318)
      at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
      at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionTarget(Validator.java:342)
      at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetValidator.addInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetValidator.java:29)
      at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:943)
      at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireProcessInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1098)
      at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldBeanManager.newBeanInstance(WeldBeanManager.java:135)
      at com.oracle.injection.integration.utils.InjectionBeanCreator.newBeanInstance(InjectionBeanCreator.java:154)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.InjectionBasedWebComponentCreator.createServletInstance(InjectionBasedWebComponentCreator.java:66)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.newServletInstanceIfNecessary(StubSecurityHelper.java:358)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:311)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
      at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
      at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
      at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:86)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:660)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:600)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.getServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:408)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
      at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
      at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
      at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
      at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
      at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
      at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
      at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

Comment: Patrick, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Seu problema está um pouco vago. Poderia acrescentar mais detalhes? Você tem o [`bens.xml`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/cdi.htm#CHDEGGEF) no seu projeto? As classes injetadas possuem alguma anotação que faça delas *beans* injetáveis pelo CDI?

Comment: Outra dica específica para o Weblogic, ele já vem com uma implementação de CDI, você não precisa incluir o Weld no seu projeto (use a do App Server). Dê uma olhada na parte do manual [específica sobre CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/cdi.htm#WLPRG503) e no exemplo em `EXAMPLES_HOME\wl_server\examples\src\examples\javaee6\cdi`. Na versão 12.1.1 haviam alguns bugs relacionados a CDI, mas parece que saíram [patches](http://danielveselka.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/weblogic-1211-java-ee-6-cdi-weld.html) e que nas versões 12.1.2+ tudo já está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, eu não consegui até o momento encontrar estes exemplos. Até reinstalei atentamente o OEPE bundle para garantir que fiz uma Full Installation tal como sugerido na documentação, e após terminar a instalação o  suposto diretório que deveria conter os exemplos não aparece.

Comment: De acordo com a documentação: o diretório dos exemplos deveria ser: EXAMPLES_HOME 

ou seja:

ORACLE_HOME\user_projects\applications

Todavia na minha ORACLE_HOME só existem os seguintes diretórios:

ORACLE_HOME\coherence,
ORACLE_HOME\em,
ORACLE_HOME\install,
ORACLE_HOME\inventory,
ORACLE_HOME\oepe (eclipse),
ORACLE_HOME\OPatch,
ORACLE_HOME\oracle_common,
ORACLE_HOME\oui,
ORACLE_HOME\wlserver ...

Testei tanto no windows qto no macosx na versão OEPE 12.1.3.

Comment: Alguém pode adicionar tags relativas ao nome do webserver? weblogic, weblogic12c. Não tenho essa permissão ainda. Acredito que este problema seja bem específico do webserver visto que minhas injeções funcionam no Jboss.

Comment: Visto que o teste com o Weld não foi suficiente para que a injeção funcionasse (passou a reconhecer a annotation mas o bean injetado continua nulo), alguma idéia sobre qual jars eu teria que colocar no build path para habilitar a injeção?

Eu coloquei umas libs que achei dentro do server: wljarbuilder.jar, weblogic.jar, weblogic.server.merged.jar no build path e ele passou a reconhecer a @Inject também, todavia o teste ainda esta mal sucedido.

Comment: Patrick, sobre os exemplos: Você precisa selecionar a opção de instalação completa: No Wizard de instalação. http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/INTRO/examples.htm

Comment: No instalador do OEPE versão 12.1.3 não é possível escolher entre instalação Full ou parcial. É tudo ou nada..

Comment: Cara, tenta outra versão do instalador então. Estou com o 12.1.2 (não lembro qual instalador usei mas acho que foi o Generic), ele veio com todos os exemplos (posso zipar para ti, mas não sei se vai funcionar em outra versão... Nem sem o domínio específico de testes).

Comment: Funcionou aqui... utilizei outro instalador que eu acredito ser identico... e fiz alguns steps diferentes na configuração. Vou detalhar o que fiz para o caso de alguem encontrar o mesmo problema. De qualquer forma, muito grato @AnthonyAccioly.

Comment: Perfeito Patrick. Fico feliz de ter ajudado e por sua iniciativa de postar a resposta para ajudar outros usuários com problemas semelhantes.

Answer (score 1):

Probleminha trabalhoso, mas conseguimos resolver por aqui tanto no mac quanto no windows. Não encontramos com exatidão o que causava o problema, mas seguindo este procedimento que reproduzi em 4 ambientes até agora passou a injeção finalmente funcionar. Segue a solução:

Utilizei um instalador do OEPE 12.1.3 de 32 bits que é um bundle já vem com o eclipse Kepler e o Weblogic 12.1.3. A instalação prosseguiu normalmente, em modo full mesmo. Eu criei um novo Domain utilizando o wizard e só habilitei a ultima opção de módulos... salvo engano JAX-WS e JMS. Mantive a JDK do próprio bundle (Java 1.7.x) e continuei a instalação normalmente. Um detalhe que fiz diferente dessa vez foi na tela "Configuração Avançada" onde fora disponibilizada uma lista de itens com check box para marcar: Servidor de Administração, Gerenciador de Nós, etc... não marquei nenhuma das opções.

Criei uma Enterprise Application com um módulo EJB e um WEB apenas. Criei um EJB de teste apenas com interface local e um método público:

```
public void imprimir(){
   Syso("passou pelo EJB")
}
```

No build path no módulo EJB, na aba libraries criei uma "user library" e como conteúdo selecionei a lib weblogic.server.merged.jar ...Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules\features. Isso é o suficiente para que a anotation @Inject passe a ser reconhecida pelo Eclipse, ou seja (nada de baixar o weld por fora). Mas como fizemos isso no projeto EJB, cuidado para não esquecer de passar pela aba Order and Export para externalizar a user library que criamos (caso contrário o projeto web não vai enxerga-la por exemplo).

No build path do projeto web, criei um apontamento para o projeto EJB (sua respectiva dependencia).

Na pasta meta-inf do projeto ejb, bem como na web-inf do projeto web, criei arquivos vazios com o nome beans.xml (para ativar o CDI)

No projeto web criei um Servlet com apenas um método doGet() e nele invoquei o bean do projeto ejb após injetá-lo e finalmente ele não estava nulo. Ou seja, a injeção funcionou. Testei tanto injetando o bean através da interface local, quanto o próprio bean concreto e funcionou perfeitamente.